# How to initial ROS node by XMLRPC on ROSCPP?

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to implement C# client library.

And I tried to figure out how to init node with master and show a circle in rxgraph on roscpp. I tried to draw call graph to trace the whole procedure of ROSCPP.

My purpose of this stage is to use the "simplest" way to init ROS node and display on rxgraph.If possible,I will extend to the full features of C# client library.

And I found that in master.cpp:execute()

```
  180   XmlRpc::XmlRpcClient *c = XMLRPCManager::instance()->getXMLRPCClient(master_host, master_port, "/");

  192       b = c->execute(method.c_str(), request, response);
```

1. Is these two lines init the node with master?
2. How to send node name to master to show in rxgraph?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12613/how-to-initial-ros-node-by-xmlrpc-on-roscpp?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-01-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the API docs: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Master and http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Master_API

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2